# Failing to set an /29 network address

Tags: 10.04, networking

I'm trying to set up a server with a /29 network address (I've been given a subnet on my DSL connection).

I set the router's LAN IP to the gateway for the range (call it xxx.xxx.xxx.176).

I then proved the routing with a Windows box and pinging google - setting the IP address to xxx.xxx.xxx.177 and with a subnet of 255.255.255.248

Then I tried to set my server up - I downed the network service and edited the interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.178
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.176
```

But when I restarted the network service, I got a message `SCIOADDRT no such process`

I could ping the 177 computer, but not the gateway - and routing to external addresses was right out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a /29 your gateway address is not valid

248 = 11111 000
176 = 10110 000

Since it is a network address, not a valid host one.

Edit: Try router .177, winbox .178, linbox .179 and you should be fine.

Comment: this is only half an answer - if you think these are wrong, can you provide a suggestion on what they should be? (these are the settings I've been given by my ISP - and they work from the Windows machine)

Comment: xxx.xxx.xxx.176 gateway with 255.255.255.248 netmask is definitively wrong.

Comment: With a 255.255.255.248 netmask host addresses fall within 177-182 range (e.g. 192.168.0.177 - 192.168.0.182) while .176 and .183 are network and broadcast adresses, and they can't be assigned to host or gateway.

Comment: @HorusKol - It "shouldn't" have worked on your Windows machine.  If it did, it's related to a 169 address getting defaulted towards and network voodoo taking over.  This answer was right.

Comment: Okay - that makes sense now, thanks. The answer might have been right, but it was still only half an answer